# How to animate a view from top to bottom and stacking that view properly?

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, uiview

I want to, as properly as possible, animate a view from top to bottom. Then do the appropriate magic to handle memory allocations and such.

In other words, I want an inverse

```
UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical
```

This `modalTransitionStyle` pops the view up from bottom, while what I'd like it to do is arrive by airplane.

I've looked into some black magic `CATransition`, but I can't for the life of me find a proper way of handling memory and dismissing (or "popping off") the view with this method.

A solution as close to "as Steve Jobs intended" is much preferred.

PS: The solution does not need to deal with the view as modal. Actually dealing with it as a new "card" on the stack would be best.

Comment: Can you post an example if you were able to get this working? I'm struggling to do the same thing

Comment: I didn't get it working. Changed the design to accommodate the normal up-from-bottom animation. Maybe that IS "as Steve Jobs intended"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about UIView
`+ (void)transitionFromView:(UIView *)fromView toView:(UIView *)toView duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion`

or

`+ (void)transitionWithView:(UIView *)view duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion`